# Can't use Jquery UI in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have Jquery globally in Laravel, however I would like to include Jquery UI too.

I have a blade template like this:

```
@section('scripts')
<script src="/assets/admin/js/sessions/myjavascript.js"></script>
@stop

content...
```

Myjavascript.js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if (jQuery.ui) {
        alert("loaded");
    }
});
```

jQuery.ui isn't there. How do I implement it?

EDIT here is the extended blade:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mysite</title>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="/assets/admin/js/core/pace.js"></script>
    <link href="/assets/admin/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    @yield('styles')
</head>
<body id="app" class="layout-horizontal skin-default">
    @include('admin.layouts.partials.notifs')
    @include('admin.layouts.partials.header')
    <div class="mobile-menu-overlay"></div>
    @include('admin.layouts.partials.header-bottom')
    @yield('content')
    @include('admin.layouts.partials.footer')
    @include('admin.layouts.partials.skintools')
    <script src="/assets/admin/js/core/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/admin/js/demo/skintools.js"></script>
    @yield('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your blade files? Like the master template everything gets included in, all the sections you are using and the version of laravel?

Comment: Did you added the script for jquery.ui

Comment: Seems your JqueryUI has not been properly included

Comment: @DouwedeHaan done.

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR No and I am not sure where to put it. That is the question.

Comment: Put it inside the section @section('scripts')
<script src="/assets/admin/js/sessions/myjavascript.js"></script>
@stop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a jquery globally that means you have pulled it via npm. 
If so then you can pull jquery-ui via npm as below

```
npm install jquery-ui
```

Else you can use cdn links in your page 
as below

In HEAD include css

```
@section('styles')
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
@endsection
```

in blade

```
@section('scripts')
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/admin/js/sessions/myjavascript.js"></script>
@stop
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Answer updated as your question was updated. (Updated blade template)

Answer (score 6):

I was need autocomplete from jquery-ui

1. Run `npm install jquery-ui --save-dev`
2. Add inside

***your-app-location**/resources/assets/js/app.js*:

```
import 'jquery-ui/themes/base/all.css';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/autocomplete.js';
```

This way you will have ui plugin on every page

Answer (score 2):

First make sure you load your jquery.ui properly (1 way would be to use cdn as Vaibhavraj Roham suggested).

Then when you make sure you're loading it properly try this:

I'm not sure how you've got your views set up, but chances are you are using section `scripts` in another subview as well and it overrides this one.

Try doing this (adding @parent):

```
@section('scripts')
@parent
<script src="/assets/admin/js/sessions/myjavascript.js"></script>
@stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@push('scripts')
<script src="/assets/admin/js/sessions/myjavascript.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if (jQuery.ui) {
        alert("loaded");
    }
});
</script>
@endpush
```